# Reuse lines of code in Stata, Similar to JavaScript function?

Tags: stata

I have some lines of code in a Stata do-file that I would like to reuse/execute and different points in the do file. Similar to a JavaScript function... however I do not necessarily need an input variable.

For example, I have some code:

```
*code to reuse
foreach x in test1 test2 test3{
rename variable_`x' variablenew_`x'
}
```

and I want to execute those 3 lines of code at various points in the do file. As if there was a way to label those three lines `codeA` and then `execute codeA` later in the do file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check `help program`.

Comment: Incidentally, the example doesn't need a loop. It's one line with `rename groups`.

Comment: Cross-posted on Statalist: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1292090-reusing-lines-of-code-similar-to-javascript-function Telling us about cross-postings is always helpful and polite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `help program`.

An example program (that takes no arguments):

```
// define program
capture program drop hello
program hello
    display "hello world!"
end

// try it out
hello
```